# Publish to multiple friends' timeline (batch)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share, facebook-timeline

Is is legal to publish to multiple friends timeline?

The Send Dialog * doesn't work at the moment, so this was my best solution... I just can't seem to find any documentation that says it's legal.

Reference: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/254812797906360?browse=search_4eef63ccbdbb36463851090

Comment: We are not lawyers. We are programmers. I wouldn't recommend taking legal advice from the internet at all.